# Put an index to a model with ng-options for a simple array

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

For the following code (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyBVN/)):

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="ampm" ng-options="currOption for currOption in ['AM', 'PM']"></select>
    AM/PM: {{ampm}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ampm = "AM";
}
```

The result is, HTML:

```
<select ng-model="ampm" ng-options="currOption for currOption in ['AM', 'PM']" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    <option value="0" selected="selected">AM</option>
    <option value="1">PM</option>
</select>
```

... which is perfectly fine. However, `'AM'` and `'PM'` are being put into the `ampm` model. Is it possible to put an index like 0 or 1 into this model? I want to have integer indexes which refer to the position in array, but not the value at this position which would need to recalculate.

**UPDATE**

Is there a way to avoid creating an array of pairs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the select to use the index of the element as the model.

This uses the `ng-options` syntax of `select as label for value in array` as detailed in the Angular docs: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

I've updated the jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/EyBVN/28/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select 
    ng-model="ampm" 
    ng-options="options.indexOf(currOption) as currOption for currOption in options"></select>
    AM/PM: {{ampm}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.options = ['AM', 'PM'];
    $scope.ampm = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select ng-model="selectItem" ng-options="currOption as currOption.value for currOption in ampm"></select>
    AM/PM: {{selectItem.name}}
</div>
```

*controller*

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.ampm = [{name: "AM",value: "0" },{name: "PM",value: "1" }];

    $scope.selectItem = $scope.ampm[0];
}
```

Demo <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyBVN/27/)</kbd>

Comment: Yes, this requires transforming the array into a new collection. I just wanted to know if I can avoid this.

Comment: The compiled HTML markup is perfectly fine. So, numbers as values are ok and I want to get them into the model, not the captions.